# Reverse the values in a __m512i register

Tags: c++, x86, simd, avx512

I'd like to reverse the order of all values in a `__m512i` register.
My main problem is that I am not finding an explanation of how to use all the different shuffle operations. I already tried `_mm512_shuffle_epi32` but I don't find any explanation how the `_MM_PERM_AAAA`, `_MM_PERM_AAAB`, ... actually work and by just trying them I don't get exactly how to use them.

Comment: Have you tried reading reference pages for those intrinsics?

Comment: What size are the elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
const __m512i reverseMask = _mm512_set_epi32 (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15);
__m512i reversed = _mm512_permutevar_epi32(reverseMask,ObjectToReverse);
```

Note, that the "reverseMask" is no real mask and instead a register that holds the positions for each object in the register to reverse.

Comment: That only reverses/shuffles 32-bit words. It does not reverse bytes in a word. Also see [`_mm512_shuffle_epi32`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm512_shuffle_epi32&expand=4744) in the Intel Intrinsics Guide.

Comment: Yup, `vpermd` or `vpermq` is the best way.  If you need finer granularity than that, AVX512BW has `vpermw` and AVX512VBMI has `vpermb`.  Without those, use `vpermq` and then reverse within 16-byte lanes with `vpshufb`.  @jww: `_mm512_shuffle_epi32` (`vpshufd`) is an in-lane shuffle.  It's not useful for this, because even AVX512F has lane-crossing shuffles with the same element size.

Comment: Actually, [`vshufi64x2 zmm, same,same, imm8`](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/VSHUFF32x4_VSHUFF64x2_VSHUFI32x4_VSHUFI64x2) can get the lane-crossing done with an immediate control operand, shuffling with 128-bit granularity, but it's slower on KNL (2-source shuffle) than `vpermd/q`.  Of course, `vpshufb zmm` is AVX512BW and isn't available on KNL anyway.